# In Tensorflow, how do I generate a scalar summary?

Tags: tensorflow

Does anyone have a minimal example of using a SummaryWriter with a scalar_summary in order to see (say) a cross entropy result during a training run?

The example [given in the documentation](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html):

```
merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/mnist_logs', sess.graph_def)
total_step = 0
while training:
    total_step += 1
    session.run(training_op)
    if total_step % 100 == 0:
        summary_str = session.run(merged_summary_op)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, total_step)
```

Returns an error: TypeError: Fetch argument None of None has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.)
When I run it.

If I add a:

```
tf.scalar_summary('cross entropy', cross_entropy)
```

operation after my cross entropy calculation, then instead I get the error:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float

Which suggests that I need to add a feed_dict to the

```
summary_str = session.run(merged_summary_op)
```

call, but I am not clear what that feed_dict should contain....

Comment: In this website you have more help if you provide a MWE, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3):

The `feed_dict` should contain the same values that you use for running the `training_op`. It basically specifies the input values to your network for which you want to calculate the summaries.

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably coming from:

```
session.run(training_op)
```

Did you paste the example code into a version of the mnist code that requires a feed_dict for feeding in training examples?  Check the backtrace it gave you (and include it above if that doesn't solve the problem).

Comment: I have had a look through the mnist example, and seen the usage that you mentioned, and as you have observed it does use a feed_dict (for images), the problem here is what should a feed_dict for scalars contain?

Comment: What is `training_op`?  Is it not from the mnist code?

Comment: 'training_op' is whatever operation you have defined for the training, a call to 'tf.train.AdamOptimizer' or 'tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer' for example. That is not the source of the error however, that comes from: session.run(merged_summary_op) which needs a feed_dict with some unknown values.